# Gnochm viewer not opening error fedora 9

Tags: fedora

I installed gnochm viewer on fedora 9. It shows the icon CHM Viewer. But when I click it, nothing happens. What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have not installed it correctly please refer to [this](http://omrudi.wordpress.com/2008/10/02/how-to-install-chm-viewer-gnochm-in-fedora-9/) guide for the installation procedure.

Comment: I dont have internet connection. So I installed from sources. 1)Chmlib 2)pychm 3) gnochm. The installation did not show me any errors. For each of the packages I did ./configure, make and make install

Comment: GNochm also requires the follwing     *  PyCHM >= 0.8.4
    * pygtk2
    * pygtk2-libglade
    * gnome-python2
    * gnome-python2-gtkhtml2
    * gnome-python2-gconf
    * gnome-python2-bonobo
    * gnome-python2-canvas

Comment: How to check on my system which all are already installed?

Comment: did you install form rpm or did you compile it from source?

Comment: I compiled from source

Comment: Refer to http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=73739